# What is the equivalent of Flink's tumbling/session window join in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, flink-streaming

According to [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-kstream-join) of Kafka Streams, we can apply KStream-to-KStream joins only by defining a lower and upper bound:

```
KStream<String, String> joined = left.join(right,
    (leftValue, rightValue) -> ... , /* ValueJoiner */
    JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)),
    Joined.with(
      Serdes.String(), /* key */
      Serdes.Long(),   /* left value */
      Serdes.Double())  /* right value */
  );
```

This only joins elements that are near to each other defined by length of join window. However, I'm looking for joining two tumbling windows which can be done in [Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/operators/joining.html):

```
DataStream<Integer> left = ...
DataStream<Integer> right = ...

left.join(right)
    .where(<LeftKeySelector>)
    .equalTo(<RightKeySelector>)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(2)))
    .apply (new JoinFunction<Integer, Integer, String> (){
        @Override
        public String join(Integer first, Integer second) {
            return first + "," + second;
        }
    });
```

Comment: A tumbling window join is not supported out-of-the-box atm. Out-of-curiosity: what is your use case for a tumbling-window-join?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax It's mostly because of application architecture. Our app has many small operators in its first stage each calculating one aggregate using tumbling windows. The second stage blindly joins them together and compiles everything into one object without caring about contents of input streams (emitting an array of JSON objects). This way we can keep adding new aggregates into first stage and second stage automatically compiles everything into one piece of data without any major change (Just append the new input streams into join chain).